# Issue installing Leiningen on Mac

Tags: macos, clojure, osx-yosemite, leiningen

I've recently updated my Mac to Yosemite.  I installed the Java SDK version 1.8.0

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Then I updated/upgraded everything in homebrew.  Leiningen did not work, so I uninstalled and reinstalled it.

```
$ brew install leiningen
==> Downloading https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/archive/2.5.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/leiningen-2.5.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.5.1/leiningen-2.5.1-standalone.zip
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/leiningen--jar-2.5.1.zip
==> Caveats
Dependencies will be installed to:
  $HOME/.m2/repository
To play around with Clojure run `lein repl` or `lein help`.

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/leiningen/2.5.1: 8 files, 15M, built in 2 seconds
```

When I try to run Leiningen again I got the same error:

```
$ lein
(Retrieving org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.3/tools.nrepl-0.2.3.pom from central)
(Retrieving org/clojure/tools.nrepl/0.2.3/tools.nrepl-0.2.3.jar from central)
(Could not find artifact cinder:cinder-nrepl:jar:0.8.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/))
(Could not find artifact cinder:cinder-nrepl:jar:0.8.1 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/))
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable.
```

I am not using a proxy or anything like that I am on my home network.

I've tried to downgrade to version 2.4.2 of Leiningen and I've tried to just install it from the bash script off leiningen.org but that fails in the same way.

How would I be able to resolve this issue?

Thank you.  :)

Comment: The issue was in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj as @justncon pointed out.

$ cat ~/.lein/profiles.clj
{:user
  {:dependencies [[alembic "0.3.2"]]
   :plugins [[cinder/cinder-nrepl "0.8.1"]]
   :shorthand {. [alembic.still/distill alembic.still/lein]}}}

Plugins should have :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]]

Thank you again @justncon!  Made my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message it says it can't retrieve the `cinder:cinder-nrepl` (should be `cider:cider-nrepl`) dependency. This is most likely due to a typo in one of your `profiles.clj` files (or `project.clj` file if you're running the `lein` command in a project directory.)

Also, `profiles.clj` files can be found in many locations and their dependency maps are merged together in some situations, check here for more:  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md

Comment: That was it.  The issue was in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj file in the plugin section just as you pointed out.  Thank you very much @justncon!